# How to register SNS topic to bounce (or complaint) email notifications with AWS CDK C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

I have SES 'verified identity' email, that sends emails. Now using CDK I'm creating SNS topic and Lambda to handle bounce and complaint emails sent by that verified email. Topic and lambda are being created well with CDK, but I cannot find a way **how to register my topic** to bounce or complaint email notifications (manually it's easy, but not clear how to do it with AWS CDK)

```
var myLambdaFunction =  new Function(...
var topic = new Topic(this, "BounceTopic", new TopicProps{TopicName = "BounceTopic",   Fifo = false });
topic.AddSubscription(new LambdaSubscription(myLambdaFunction, new LambdaSubscriptionProps()));
           
//I've tried to use this code to subscribe topic to Bounce, but creating BounceActionConfig does not even appear in CloudFormation template (maybe I need to use it as a parameter, but where?)
            var bounceActionConfig = new BounceActionConfig {
                Message = "Bounce email",
                Sender = props.EmailSender,//the verified SES identity email address
                SmtpReplyCode = "smtpReplyCode",
                TopicArn = topic.TopicArn
            };
```

So I need to make my cdk code to find SES email identity and set it's Bounce and/or complaint notifications to my newly created topic. Should I use this BounceActionConfig or there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find out how to achieve this purely within the CDK.  So after my CDK script has run, I run a bash script which uses the AWS CLI to complete the job.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e
set -u

export STACK_NAME=...

EMAIL_IDENTITY_ARN=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name "$STACK_NAME" --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='EmailIdentityArn'].OutputValue" --output text)
EMAIL_TOPIC_ARN=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name "$STACK_NAME" --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='EmailTopicArn'].OutputValue" --output text)

aws ses set-identity-notification-topic --identity "$EMAIL_IDENTITY_ARN" --notification-type "Bounce" --sns-topic "$EMAIL_TOPIC_ARN"
aws ses set-identity-notification-topic --identity "$EMAIL_IDENTITY_ARN" --notification-type "Complaint" --sns-topic "$EMAIL_TOPIC_ARN"
aws ses set-identity-notification-topic --identity "$EMAIL_IDENTITY_ARN" --notification-type "Delivery" --sns-topic "$EMAIL_TOPIC_ARN"

# Disable notifications via email of bounce or complaint
aws ses set-identity-feedback-forwarding-enabled --identity "$EMAIL_IDENTITY_ARN" --no-forwarding-enabled
```

To clarify, the bash script retrieves two parameters which are set in my (TypeScript) CDK code as follows:

```js
const FROM_ADDRESS = "test@example.com";
const region = Stack.of(scope).region;
const account = Stack.of(scope).account;
const emailIdentity = new EmailIdentity(scope, "Identity", {identity: Identity.email(FROM_ADDRESS)});
const emailIdentityArn = `arn:aws:ses:${region}:${account}:identity/${FROM_ADDRESS}`;
new CfnOutput(scope, "EmailIdentityArn", {value: emailIdentityArn});

const topic = new sns.Topic(scope, "EmailTopicArn");
new CfnOutput(scope, "EmailTopicArn", {value: topic.topicArn});
```

NOTE: I believe the `set-identity-notification-topic` CLI command is idempotent, so it would be OK to run this as part of a CI/CD setup.

Comment: Sounds like this could be solved with a SDK call custom resource - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsCustomResource.html